# Can I have auto pairing tag in Textmate?

Tags: text-editor, textmate

for example, I type

```
<html>
```

, this there any short cuts to insert

```
</html>
```

for me? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles -> HTML -> Insert Close Tag (Option + Command + period)